# .NET Core 2.0 HTTPs timing out on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-certificate-manager, aws-sdk-net

After successfully deploying my asp.net core 2.0 API to AWS, using AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017, I can access my api only by HTTP. HTTPS requests fail with a connection timeout.

So far I've done the following: Setup a Certificate on AWS Certificate Manager which points to my Personal Domain, properly mapped on Route 53. My API runs fine on localhost using a dev-cert and amazon documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSLNET.SingleInstance.html) seems cloudy to me as it refers to S3 and not Certificate Manager.

Comment: Make sure under the configuration on elb load balancer is set to allow port 443. Check elb -> your application -> configuration (left menu) -> load balancer

Comment: It's a micro environment so there's no load balancer there. I've checked the inbound ports for my security group and 443 is allowed inbound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up adding a load balancer to my Application, setting the max. intances to 1 and applying the SSL certificate to the Load Balancer.

On the Load Balancer I've set the port 443 as a listener and redirecting to 80 on my API. Then it all worked.